# Backbone Router in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I am using the Backbone.js router to fire certain initialization methods when the user hits certain URL routes.  So going to `/posts/1` via a vanilla anchor tag should fire whatever callback is associated with `/posts/:id` in my Backbone router.  This works fine in modern browsers when `Backbone.history.start({ pushState : true })` is set. However, *in IE*, users who try to hit `/posts/1` will be redirected to `/#posts/1`, which is just my home page with a meaningless hash string.

To be clear, I do not need pushState.  I am not trying to **push** URLs to the browser history.  I am just trying to read them, then fire a callback, which should be feasible in any browser.

Seems like simple functionality but I am stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need your server to respond to the URL /posts/1, and is that considered a different page for your app? Could you just pull down the post information in an XHR and display it on the page?

Comment: I think you need to post some code -- it's a bit hard to tell what you mean.  The redirect to the URL fragment is normal fallback behavior for browsers that don't support push-state.  Are you saying the route isn't getting hit correctly in those cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can answer my own question here.  The type of functionality I needed here could be achieved the following way:

```
var suffix_pattern = new RegExp('\/?' + config.history_root + '\/?','i');

// if IE
if (!Modernizr.history) {

    // initialize router/Backbone.history, but turn off route parsing,
    // since non-window.history parsing will look for a hash, and not finding one,
    // will break our shit.
    Backbone.history.start({ silent: true, hashChange: true });

    // convert any post-# elements to a standard URL to be parsed by our router
    var subroute = window.location.hash.replace('#', '/').split('?')[0],
           route = window.location.pathname.replace(suffix_pattern, '') + subroute;

    Backbone.history.loadUrl(route);
} else {
    Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, silent: true });
    Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.getFragment().replace(suffix_pattern, '').split('?')[0]);
}
```

Comment: you really going to production with that "// will break our shit." comment? LOL! too funny. anyhow, glad you figured it out.

Comment: My production build strips out all comments.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me: Backbone.history.start({root: '/my_app_dir_here/'});

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about ajax page loads in browsers that don't support pushState, use option `{hashChange: false}`. This will cause hard page loads every time a route changes.

e.g.

`Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, hashChange:false });`

From the Backbone.js docs:

> If you'd like to use pushState, but have browsers that don't support it natively use full page refreshes instead, you can add {hashChange: false} to the options.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer above applies to an issue in a Backbone version that is now over two years old.  The problem above no longer exists.